# Purging messages from stream after joining them in Kafka Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka Streams to join by key two different types of messages, coming from two different Kafka topics. I am using a [Sliding time window](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#sliding-time-windows). This window policy retains the information from streams for an amount of type that is independent of the fact that a message joined something or not.

In case of a very high throughput of the input streams, the topics created by Kafka to perform the join can grow very quickly, consuming a huge amount of disk space.

Is there the possibility to purge the messages from the above topic once joined? In this way, I will assume that a message joins at most once with another message with the same key.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Since version 2.4.0, you can configure a stream-stream join via the `StreamJoined` parameter (cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-479%3A+Add+StreamJoined+config+object+to+Join).

You can create a `WindowedStoreSupplier` via `Stores` factory class, and specify the supplier on the `StreamJoined` object that you pass into the `join()` method.

**Original Answer**

You can decrease the retention time, via `until()` parameter:

```java
stream1.join(stream2, JoinWindows.of(...).until(/*put retention time here*/);
```

The specified retention time will be used for local stores as well as for the underlying changelog topic. Note, if the changelog topic exists already, changing `until()` will *not* update the topic config -- you would need to update the topic config manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, how can I use this feature to purge joined messages?

Comment: You cannot -- and why would you want to do this? The semantics of the join define if a record is joinable or not and there is no need to purge records "manually"

Comment: Ok, I suppose you are right. The only feasible solution is to narrow down the joining window, at this point. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, how about the state store in the state directory? It seems that a directory is created for each 12 hour window (id-lkp-this-join-store.1610193600000, id-lkp-this-join-store.1610236800000,  id-lkp-this-join-store.1610280000000...etc)

Will these be purged eventually? How can I decrease the retention? My joinWindow config have 1 hour grace period JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(1500)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(3597000))

Comment: In older version, you can use `until()`. In newer versions you can pass in a `StreamJoined` parameter into `join()` method to set it by specifying a `WindowStoreSupplier` (that you can create via `Stores` factory class) on `StreamJoined`.

Answer (score -1):

0.11.0.0 introduces a new API `deleteRecords` in AdminClient and a script named `kafka-delete-records` which can be used to delete all records before the given offset. You could use them to purge the data that is no longer needed.

See [KIP-107](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-107%3A+Add+deleteRecordsBefore%28%29+API+in+AdminClient) for details.

Comment: Sorry, how your response is related to my issue? I mean, can you give me a concrete example?

Comment: You should determine the intermediate join topic and the offset before which there are no unprocessed records, then feed a json file like `{"partitions":[{"topic": "KSTREAM-JOIN-0000000000", "partition": 0,"offset": <your_offset>}],"version":1}` to kafka-delete-records script.

Comment: Well, something complicated in the context of an enterprise application.